# Oracle Apex send email with Interactive Report or Region attached

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-apex

I've been looking for a solution all around with no success.
Is there a way to send an email from my Apex App with an interactive report (or a PL/SQL dynamic region) as an attachment?
(either automatically (weekly for example) or by the click of a button)

Any guidance would be truly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Interactive Report there are two built in options under the "[Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Dg4.png)" menu to send you report as an attachment via email:

- [Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkOe5.png) for single
- [Subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRZUf.png) for iterative

Just make sure you set the "Email" option under your report [Download attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6CKh.png).